# R ggplot code for changing date display

Tags: r

I have a graph that I am making in R and the first issue I have is that my dates are not formatted correctly, they are formatted as factors and that is causing them to be graphed in random orders on the X axis (obviously I want them in chronological order for a time series).
Ideally I also want to be able to show only every 3 months and show them as Month year in the %B %y format or May 2007, I just am not sure where to add this code in my script it seems to not work wherever I add it...

Thanks heaps
Anna (newbie)

The following is the code that I have working, but the dates aren't in chronological order on the X axis which is a big issue...

```
> # ggplot2 library
library(ggplot2)

# The easiest way to get tidyr is to install the whole tidyverse:
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("tidyverse")

#load data or read data file, first set your working directory as the file that has your data files inside of it, to do this go to Session> Set working directory and pick the file
read.csv(file="Top25/RA_PH_0m_top25.csv", header=TRUE)

#next create a variable to read.csv the file in question
read_data1 <- read.csv(file="Top25/RA_PH_0m_top25.csv", header=TRUE)

#the easiest way to gather data is the following, gathering columns 2-9
gather(read_data1, zOTU, RA, 2:9, na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE)
gather_data1 <- gather(read_data1, zOTU, RA, 2:9, na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE)

#now you can graph the new gather_data1 in a stacked area plot
p <- ggplot(gather_data1, aes(x = Date, y = RA, group = zOTU, fill = zOTU)) +
  geom_area(position="fill", color = "black")

#p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00",
#                                     "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00",
#                                    "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999", "#E69F00",
#                                   "#999999", "#E69F00", "#999999"))
p
```

[this is the stacked area plot the the above code creates, notice the dates are not chronological](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3SNK.png)

Comment: What is the type of your `date` variable? You can find out by typing `class(gather_data1$Date)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your dates with as.Date or as.Posixct functions.

For example:

```
gather_data1$Date <- as.Date(gather_data1$Date,format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

the in ggplot you can use:

```
p <- ggplot(gather_data1, aes(x = Date, y = RA, group = zOTU, fill = zOTU)) +
geom_area(position="fill", color = "black")+
scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %Y", date_breaks  ="3 month")
```